# How to synchronize designer template and C# sharp code in Visual Studio Express 2012?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

Let's say, I create a page `MyPage` in a WPF application `MyApp` with Visual Studio 2012 Express.

Very often, when I try to access newly created elements of `MyPage.xaml` in `MyPage.xaml.cs`, I get an error message like

> The name “group_combobox” does not exist in the current context

This happens even though other elements of the same page / the same context do exist and are available in my C# sharp code editor window.

To give you an example of the problem, see the following `MyPage.xaml` and `MyPage.xaml.cs` which are returning the error message, when editing the `MyPage.xaml.cs` file:

**MyPage.xaml**

```
<Page x:Class="MyApp.MyPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="1024"
    Title="MyApp - MyPage" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">

    <Button x:Name="MyPage_back_button" Content="Back" Margin="10,100,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" Height="50"/>
    <StackPanel Margin="0" x:Name="settings_stackpanel">
        <GroupBox Header="Group" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" Margin="10" Height="100">
            <ComboBox x:Name="group_combobox" Height="62" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        </GroupBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

**MyPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class MyPage : Page
    {

        public MyPage()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("MyPage");

            InitializeComponent();

            group_combobox.Items.Clear(); // <-- error: The name “group_combobox” does not exist in the current context
            string test = MyPage_back_button.ToString(); // <-- no error
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the error is only thrown for one of two elements from the same page. I think, there is somehow somewhere described how this "context" looks and what it contains. And at a certain point there is some kind of "synchronization" or something like that. 
I noticed this behaviour before, and it solved "magically" that I think I somehow accidentally fired that trigger or the mechanism that is responsible for this synchronization.

Do you know how to trigger that kind of synchronization and how to access the information about "the current context"?

p.s. Rebuilding the project did not solve the problem

Comment: Try put this line `group_combobox.Items.Clear()` in `Window.Loaded` event or in `Window.ContentRendered`.

Comment: Hey Anatoliy, thx for your hint. I don't think it will help, because this is a "compile time" error and I want to know the variable's properties before starting the application (because I want Visual Studio to analyse the variable and give me information about the variables attributes and methods and with those errors the build wont be successful). As long as this problem appears in the editor, the application is not starting anyway :/